# Logic error when checking diagonal - nQueens

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

After solving my error with values-list and being able to run my program until the end, I found that my diagonal check seems to have a logic error. My input is as follows:

(THREAT? '(1 3) '((1 0)(2 4)(3 0)(4 0)(5 0)(6 0)(7 0)(8 0)))

The first argument being a board space that we are testing is ok or not to place a queen and the second argument is the state of the board, y values 1-8 determine the column positions of a piece and a 0 value would indicate that x value row would hold no piece. My code is as follows:

```
(defun diagonal(point1 point2)
    (= (abs (- ( car point1 ) ( car point2 )))
       (abs (- ( cadr point1 ) ( cadr point2 ))))
)

(defun THREAT?(x y)
    ; Checks threat on the vertical
    (when (not (eq (values-list (cdr (nth (- (car x) 1 ) y )) ) '0 ) )
            (return-from THREAT? t)
    )
    (loop for i from 0 to (list-length y)

            ; Checks threat on the horizontal
            when (eq (values-list ( cdr x  )) (values-list (cdr (nth i y))) )
                    do (return-from THREAT? t)
            ; With the help of the diagonal function checks along the diagonal
            when (diagonal x (nth i y) )
                    do (return-from THREAT? t)
    )
)
```

If my understanding is correct my program should loop through every single element of y. It will pass the x and the current y pair to the diagonal function. The diagonal function will minus the two and absolute value them and check if they are equal (if they are diagonal then they should be ex. (1 2) and (2 3) are diagonal and therefore |1 - 2| = 1 and |2 - 3| = 1). The diagonal function should return true if these numbers are equivalent. The corresponding when statement should only activate when it receives a true from the diagonal function and yet it seems to always return true, even when I give the program a completely blank board. How do I fix diagonal to correctly determine a threat on the board? Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You still have VALUES-LIST in the code... Why?

Comment: I removed them from the top where they were causing errors. It's just that in the two other checks they were not causing any problems and working correctly so I kept them, but I could remove them and edit the post if they are really unnecessary or a nuisance.

Comment: VALUES-LIST makes no sense. (VALUES-LIST (CDR x)) is just (second x). You should write clear code.

Comment: Ok, I will go about changing that and I'll edit the post when I finish

Comment: What is `(1 3)` in the first argument? What is the 1 and what is the 3?

Comment: (1 3) is where we will add a new piece, as if we would say "If we put something here will it cause problems?" in this argument 1 is the row (x) and 3 is the column (y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I have rewritten your code to better Lisp style.**

- much better naming.
- procedures with useful names make comments redundant
- individual procedures are better testable
- got rid of the VALUES-LIST nonsense
- get rid of all CAR, CDR, CADR. Use FIRST and SECOND.
- introduced accessors for x and y components of a point
- got rid of the strange control flow with RETURN-FROM, replaced it with a simple OR
- actually directly iterate over a list, instead of using NTH all the time
- EQ is not for comparing number equality, use = instead
- don't place parentheses alone on a line.
- indent and format the code correctly
- don't put spaces between parentheses
- put a space between an atom and an open parenthesis

**Code:**

```
(defun get-x (point)
  (first point))

(defun get-y (point)
  (second point))

(defun diagonal? (point1 point2)
  (= (abs (- (get-x point1) (get-x point2)))
     (abs (- (get-y point1) (get-y point2)))))

(defun vertical? (point)
  (not (zerop (get-y point))))

(defun horizontal? (point1 point2)
  (= (get-y point1)
     (get-y point2)))

(defun threat? (point list-of-columns)
  (or (vertical? (nth (1- (get-x point)) list-of-columns))
      (loop for point2 in list-of-columns
            when (or (horizontal? point point2)
                     (diagonal?   point point2))
            return t)))
```

**Example**

Now we can trace the three threat predicates:

```
? (trace vertical? diagonal? horizontal?)
NIL
```

Now you can call your example:

```
? (threat? '(1 3) '((1 0) (2 4) (3 0) (4 0) (5 0) (6 0) (7 0) (8 0)))
0> Calling (VERTICAL? (1 0)) 
<0 VERTICAL? returned NIL
0> Calling (HORIZONTAL? (1 3) (1 0)) 
<0 HORIZONTAL? returned NIL
0> Calling (DIAGONAL? (1 3) (1 0)) 
<0 DIAGONAL? returned NIL
0> Calling (HORIZONTAL? (1 3) (2 4)) 
<0 HORIZONTAL? returned NIL
0> Calling (DIAGONAL? (1 3) (2 4)) 
<0 DIAGONAL? returned T
T
```

**This should help, so that you can better debug your code... Look at the trace output.**

**A version which does not use empty column descriptions**

```
(defun get-x (point)
  (first point))

(defun get-y (point)
  (second point))

(defun diagonal? (point1 point2)
  (= (abs (- (get-x point1) (get-x point2)))
     (abs (- (get-y point1) (get-y point2)))))

(defun vertical? (point list-of-columns)
  (let ((point2 (find (get-x point) list-of-columns :key #'get-x)))
    (and point2 (not (zerop (get-y point2))))))

(defun horizontal? (point1 point2)
  (= (get-y point1)
     (get-y point2)))

(defun threat? (point list-of-columns)
  (or (vertical? point list-of-columns)
      (loop for point2 in list-of-columns
            when (or (horizontal? point point2)
                     (diagonal?   point point2))
            return t)))

(defun print-board (board)
  (format t "~%+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+")
  (dotimes (y 8)
    (terpri)
    (dotimes (x 8)
      (format t "|~a" (if (member (list x y) board :test #'equal) "x" " ")))
    (format t "|~%+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+")))
```

Example:

```
CL-USER 138 > (threat? '(1 2) '((2 4)))
NIL

CL-USER 139 > (print-board '((1 2) (2 4)))

+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |x| | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | |x| | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
NIL
```

Another example:

```
CL-USER 140 > (threat? '(1 2) '((2 4) (4 5)))
T

CL-USER 141 > (print-board '((1 2) (2 4) (4 5)))

+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |x| | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | |x| | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | |x| | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
NIL
```

Comment: I tried out your code, and your code produces the same issue of being always true. I used the input (THREAT? '(1 2) '((1 0)(2 4)(3 0)(4 0)(5 0)(6 0)(7 0)(8 0))) which should not have a threat and yet it still returns true. Was your answer simply reformatting or is your code supposed to produce the correct output and how would you go about fixing this error?

Comment: @JohnBucher: I did not fix the error. But I improved your not-so-optimal code, so you can actually look at the trace output and you easily will find an error.

Comment: well using your improved code the one problem holding it back is still the diagonal function. Do you see any apparent problems with it? It really should minus the x's and y's, absolute value, and check if they are equal. I don't understand how (1 2)(2 4) |1 - 2| = 1 |2 - 4| = 2 1 = 2 when 1 does not equal 2. I am coding on the command line and using files and can not find a way to debug when on the command line

Comment: What? (diagonal? '(1 2) '(2 4)) is NIL.

Comment: Look at the trace output for `(THREAT? '(1 2) '((1 0)(2 4)(3 0)(4 0)(5 0)(6 0)(7 0)(8 0)))`. Then you see for which values DIAGONAL? actually gets called and when it returns T. See my example above how to trace the functions.

Comment: I copied all of your code as you gave it and tried out the threat? function and giving it (threat? '(1 2) '((1 0)(2 4)(3 0)(4 0)(5 0)(6 0)(7 0)(8 0))) will return true when it shouldn't, but now that I test just diagonal on its own I see that diagonal is actually returning Nil. Do you get a different result than me and if you do get true, then what could be wrong with the loop?

Comment: Would I be able to change your return t to a (return-from THREAT? t) and then add a (return-from THREAT? nil) at the end of my loop? This would be like saying: exit threat if you found something, no reason to keep going, but if the loop makes it all the way through then it must be false. I tried altering your return t in the when to return-from but am having errors from trying to change it. Does when always need a true, or is return-from a possibility? right now it is: when (or (cond1)(cond2)) return t; so is it possible to change the return to return-from? I believe this should fix it.

Comment: Don't know if you are still checking this but I thought you would be at least a little interested since your code (which was using mine to be honest) had the same problem. It would loop through and for example would find (3 0) if our input was (1 2) it would do: |3 - 1| = 2 |0 - 2| = 2 and would return false. Adding a conditional to ensure that a point2 with a y of 0 is not accepted I believe will fix the problem

Comment: @JohnBucher: right. That was the problem. That's why I said look at the trace and check how DIAGONAL? is called.

Comment: @JohnBucher: the next way to simplify it: `((1 0)(2 4)(3 0)(4 0)(5 0)(6 0)(7 0)(8 0))`   ->  I would get rid of all the places where there are zeros. Since there is no queen, they are not needed anyway. Just list the places where there are queens. This way you don't need to deal with it in `DIAGONAL?`.

Comment: What would be the best and most logical way to "remove" points that have a 0 y value? Could I do it in the same loop as the horizontal and diagonal calls, would it need its own loop to run through the points before giving it to our horizontal and diagonal loop, etc?

Comment: @JohnBucher: see the answer above

Comment: I know that this might not be pretty code but I attempted to use an if statement in diagonal to ensure that no point2 with a y of 0 would be attempted and would always return nil like so: (if (not (eq (cadr point2) 0 ) ) (... absolute value stuff) (return-from diagonal nil) ). I know it is not the best that it could be but I am so very close to finishing it with this code which I made. The error I get is *Nil is not a number* and was wondering if you could see why. I was looking online and I thought that adding an else to my if could catch the problem but it didn't seem to do the trick

Comment: ^ In this above example, diagonal on it's own will work fine, but when running it from threat? it will generate the *Nil is not a number* error, leading me to believe that it is somehow in issue with the call: (eq (diagonal x (nth i y) ) t )

Comment: Found the solution to my problem, thank you very much for your help!